# Regression on subset of observations. Is this valid?

Tags: regression, linear-model

I have a dataset that compiles voting results for transportation referendums. Each observation is a city that has held a referendum. I am interested in the community factors contributing to support so I have demographic and economic variables for each observation as well.

The referendums are advisory which means that in some cases passage has led to the construction of new transport infrastructure and in some cases passage has NOT led to any actual construction.

Is it legitimate to run the same regression test on a) the universe of observations, b) the subset of cities where passage resulted in construction, and c) the subset of cities where passage did not result in construction?

I am not planning on making conclusions comparing coefficients across each test. Rather, I wanted to see if, in isolation, the three universes have different or similar variables that are significant.

Would running the three side-by-side be legitimate; or should I construct an interaction variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [dummy variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)) $U=0, 1$ equals to $1$ for cities where passage resulted in construction and $0$ for cities where passage did NOT.

Look at a model $Y=aX+bU+c + \epsilon$. On the subpopulation on which $U=1$ the model is $Y=aX+(b+c) + \epsilon$, and on the subpopulation on which $U=0$ the model is $Y=aX+c + \epsilon$. So $b$ is the impact on $Y$ of being a city where passage resulted in construction, once the impact of variable $X$ has been removed.

This is given by a standard regression analysis. The nice thing of this approach is that the regression will give the significance of $b$, that is if changing of subpopulation has an effect on the dependence of $Y$ on $X$.

And technically, you are doing 3 analysis in 1 go.